# How can I use dictionary to map keys located in one string list to values located in another string list using C#?

Tags: c#, string, list, dictionary

I have two string lists; myFruits and myColors.

myFruits is in the following format:

```
 ["Apple", "Banana", "Guava", "Blueberry"] //key
```

myColors is in the following format:

```
["Red", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue"]  //value
```

I want to be able to map the keys of myFruits to values of myColors serially using a Dictionary and getting
 something like the following in my output.

```
Apple:Red
Banana:Yellow
Guava:Green
Blueberry:Blue
```

I tried using zip in my code but something I am doing is not right as it is not printing the correctly.

```
var dic = myFruits.Zip(myColors, (k, v) => new { k, v }).ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);
```

How can I achieve the desired output? This is just a sample example, I could have multiple values on my list on every run but there will always be equal no. of items on both lists no matter what the number is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you printing it, and what does it show? Your use of `Zip` looks fine.

Comment: works for me https://dotnetfiddle.net/CYAItl

Comment: I was not printing it correctly. It works correctly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks more like a output problem. See the code below to make the `<fruit>:<color>` string.

```
var myFruits = new []{"Apple", "Banana", "Guava", "Blueberry"};
var myColors = new []{"Red", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue"};

var dic = myFruits.Zip(myColors, (k, v) => new { k, v }).ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);

foreach(var kvp in dic)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key}:{kvp.Value}");
}
```

Outputs:

```
Apple:Red
Banana:Yellow
Guava:Green
Blueberry:Blue
```

Comment: It was indeed an output issue. I was not printing it out correctly. Working ok now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a problem with not using a LINQ extension?

```
var myFruits = new [] {"Apple", "Banana"};
var myColors = new [] {"Red", "Yellow"};
var mapping = new Dictionary<string, string>();

for(var i = 0; i < myFruits.Count(); i++)
{
  mapping.Add(myFruits[i], myColors[i]);
}
```

Comment: Too old style! (and too readable too, compared to the Linq `Zip` way). Linq is great, but is the accepted `var dic = myFruits.Zip(myColors, (k, v) => new { k, v }).ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);` better than your 3 lines of code? I don't think so